# How can I set a listener that fires when a BottomAppBar hides/shows?

Tags: android, android-bottomappbar

I have a `BottomAppBar` that hides and shows when a `RecyclerView` is scrolled via its attribute `hideOnScroll`.
I would like to change the `FloatingActionButton` alignment mode when the `BottomAppBar` hides or shows.

I have not found any listeners or functions on how to achieve this. Are there any and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a listener to work with.

I achieved my wished behavior by overriding the `BottomAppBar.Behavior` class and its methods `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`.

In those methods I just change the `BottomAppBars` FAB alignment mode appropriately and thats it. Now just tell the `BottomAppBar` to use this new behavior class via its XML attribute `app:layout_behavior="MyBottomAppBarBehavior"`.

But I figured this is rather bad because it somewhat eats a lot of resources and wont show smoothly on lower-end or older devices. It also re-aligns the `BottomAppBar`'s `menu` when you do it quickly.

So I decided to just hide the FAB when the `BottomAppBar` is hidden and vice versa. I achieved this similarily by overriding the `FloatingActionButton.Behavior` class and do stuff in there. You can find good tutorials for this online.